# Python: print multi-lines when using format string

Tags: python, printing, string-formatting

When I try to print multi-lines with format string in python, the bash show the error like that:

```
a = 'tony'
b = '20'
print ("I am %s\n"+
       "I am %s years old\n"
       % (a,b))
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I'm wondering what's wrong with that and what's the right way to use format string to print multi-lines.

---

if i write code like this, it'll output correctly. However, the single line code will be too long, that's not what I want.

```
print ("I am %s\nI am %s years old\n" % (a,b))
```

Comment: Just remove the `+`

Comment: in case you want to deepen your knowledge There is a comprehensive site about python format strings: https://pyformat.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `line continuation` here, use `\`

Try this :

```
a = 'tony'
b = '20'
print("I am %s\n" \
      "I am %s years old\n" \
       % (a,b))

I am tony
I am 20 years old
```

or you can just remove `+`

```
print("I am %s\n"
      "I am %s years old\n"
       % (a,b))

I am tony
I am 20 years old
```

Comment: Your statement that "you need line continuation, use \" is not supported by the code you show.

Comment: Thanks, Edited, please check :)

Comment: NO!  You missed my point, you don't need line continuation characters here.  The code you showed previously worked fine.  Like C, in python adjacent string literals are glued together.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @cdarke can I add your method also in my answer, for the future users ? or you can also edit my answer

Comment: Feel free - your code was originally correct and I mis-lead you.